# Pyopengl - VBO with texture

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I use Python 3.6. Originally I use code like this:

```
    array_to_texture(self.board)
    glColor3fv((1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for vertex, tex  in zip(self.POINTS, self.TEX):
        glTexCoord2f(*tex)
        glVertex3fv(vertex)
    glEnd()
```

and it works. It draw square with texture in 3D space.

Now I want to use VBO to do the trick. To draw walls (with fixed color) is possible to use following code:

```
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(vertices) * 4, (c_float * len(vertices))(*vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)
```

That works perfectly. **The major question, how can I attach and draw a texture with this approach?** How Can I create some kind of buffer for texture coordinates and use it? I really struggle to find some minimal working example.

**The minor question is**, how is it possible that the `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)` line works, even though the GL_QUADS are not allowed in documentation: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDrawArrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 10.3.3 Specifying Arrays for Fixed-Function Attributes; page 402](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

> The commands
>
> ```
> void VertexPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void NormalPointer( enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void ColorPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void SecondaryColorPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void IndexPointer( enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void EdgeFlagPointer( sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void FogCoordPointer( enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> void TexCoordPointer( int size, enum type, sizei stride, const void *pointer );
> ```
>
> specify the location and organization of arrays to store vertex coordinates, normals, colors, secondary colors, color indices, edge flags, fog coordinates.
>
> ...
>
> An individual array is enabled or disabled by calling one of
>
> ```
> void EnableClientState( enum array );
> void DisableClientState( enum array );
> ```
>
> with array set to `VERTEX_ARRAY`, `NORMAL_ARRAY`, `COLOR_ARRAY`, `SECONDARY_COLOR_ARRAY`, `INDEX_ARRAY`, `EDGE_FLAG_ARRAY`, `FOG_COORD_ARRAY`, or `TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`, for the vertex, normal, color, secondary color, color index, edge flag, fog coordinate, or texture coordinate array, respectively.

This means that vertex coordinates can be specified by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) and enabled by [`glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml)

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

And texture cooridantes can be specified by [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml) and enabled by [`glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml)

```
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
```